# What does the light colored bar mean next to my Outlook.com appointments?

Tags: outlook.com, outlook.com-calendar

Next to some of my appointments in Outlook.com, there is a light colored bar. I have no idea what it means. I've read it's to make a distinction between all-day appointments and appointments with an hour, but this isn't correct, as I see it on both.

This is a screenshot of my calendar:

[image: Outlook.com calendar]

Comment: A bit hard to tell because I have a different color scheme, but in my case the lines seem to indicate if this is an invitation I have (or have not) responded to.